# relations between a set of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I have a set of polynomials. Is there a computer algebra program that gives all the algebraic relations between them ? I will prefer singular if it has this component.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by any system that supports Grobner bases. To find the relations between $\,f_1,\ldots,f_n\,$ compute the contraction of the ideal $\,(t_1-f_1,\ldots,t_n-f_n)$ to $\,\Bbb Q[t_1,\ldots,t_n].$

Comment: Could you please give me a link to the code in singular ? Thanks.

Comment: and how to find a minimal set of relations among all the relations ?

Comment: @Jack I am not familiar with singular.